# Magento 2 GET API request to external api

Tags: magento2, rest-api, curl

In magento 1 you can make get request like this:
First Authorizing object-

```
public function authorize($url)
{
    $cookie = $this->getCookieDir();
    $user = $this->getApiUser();
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '.....-API-client/1.0');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($user));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

Then

```
public function get($url)
{
    $cookie = $this->getCookieDir();
    $curl = $this->initCh($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '.......-API-client/1.0');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    $out = curl_exec($curl); # Initiate a request to the API and stores the response to variable
    $code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $out;
}
```

Now in Magento 2

```
\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl::get($uri); calls makeRequest();
```

In makeRequest(); curl_init() is called and all curlOption() are set. So there shouldn't be anymore need to do like in Magento 1? If so how this is how it should be done? -

```
/**
 * @param $url
 * @return void
 */
public function doGet($url){
    $user = $this->getApiUser();
    $this->_curl->setHeaders(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($user));
   //setting everything else
    $this->_curl->get($url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to send cURL request in Magento 2.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl $curl
   ) {
    $this->curl = $curl;
}
public function sendCurlRequest($dataToBeSend) {
   $body = json_encode($dataToBeSend);
   $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($body)
  ];
  $this->curl->write('POST', $url, $http_ver = '1.1', $headers, $body);
  //For Get Request
  $this->curl->write('GET', $url);
  $response = $this->curl->read();
}
```

Let me know in case you need further assistance.